# .htaccess Settings (Rewrite URL Rule) working on Localhost, But Not on Live Site

Tags: .htaccess, magento, url-rewriting, magento-1.7

My .htaccess Rewrite Rules are as follows:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/eshop/$ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{REQUEST_URI}index.php/eshop-new-home/ [R,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/eshop/index.php/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{REQUEST_URI}eshop-new-home/ [R,L]
```

These settings works properly on localhost, But its not working on live website. Any Solutions?

Comment: do you have apache on the live or its nginx or what?

Comment: @Meabed yes, my server is linux based with apache server on the live

Comment: have you change AllowOverride to AllowOverride All in apache config?

Comment: @Meabed : my site is hosted on other server, so i have no access to apache config. what you are telling me to change ?

Comment: Did you contact your hosting company to find out if mod_rewrite is enable and `AllowOverride` is set to `All` so that you can use `.htaccess` in your website?

Comment: @R.S : Still not yet they have answered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enable Mod Rewrite

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

and

```
AllowOverride All
```

in your apache configs